# Cannot find UTM17W84 World Geodetric Projection

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, revit

I am working on transferring QGIS data to Revit. I need my data to be in the UTM17W84 World Geodetric Projection; however, I cannot find it anywhere in the predefined projections. I am new to the software and wasn't sure if anyone could give me an alternative projection to use or how to obtain the desired projection.

Answer (score 2):

if your projection starts with UTM, it is most likely an Universal Trnasverse Mercator, in your case BASED on the World Geodetic System 84 (in short, WGS 84). So you should look after UTM zone 16 / WGS84 (probably North).

Based on the fact that EPSG codes based on WGS 84 in the Northern hemisphere start with 326 then the number of the zone, you could type 32617 in the search bar. If you are in the Southern hemisphere, then it is 32717. Alternatively, typing "UTM zone 17" should be restrictive enough to enable you to select the right projection.

Below a print screen of my "Project > properties window"

[image]